# question regarding tex design previously done by Yannis

Tags: book-design, sourcecode

i obtained a repository dump from [github](https://github.com/yannisl/phd) phd-master ( impressive work Yiannis has done i must acknowledge)
i am in the process or rereading my draft of work for self publishing- and i have looked through his work. tried to replicate one of the style he has in the package to see how it works. on his file the style06 tex had this:

reading through his test sample, i deduced the following, and here is my code  i would be glad and appreciative for a help from here - this is strictly for practice and i will change the designs and colors and  fonts later, once i get the grasp on it

i MODIFIED THE CODE - AND IT WORKS NOW - I WOULD LIKE TO HEAR YOUR INPUTS ON HOW TO IMPORVE IT . this what i use to compile

```
    \documentclass{book}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{phd}
\sethyperref
\input{defaultstyle}


\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\input{./styles/style06}
\chapter{An Inevitable Introduction}
\cxset{style06}
\expandafter\epigraph{I believe.}{08/26/19986}
\lettrine{\textcolor{orange} {N}}{}ow, I understand some of the mystery hidden from me, and mastered the craft of eavesdropping on the senses. I know it will not help much, but it is better than believing that life is fruitless and that the luck is the master. All things in this world are balanced and in their places, even those calamities, evils, and the coincidences are ordered alphabetically and preplanned!

The world has its own secret, and things disclose about its holiness and it is full of insinuations and passwords that cached in all what we see; but we do not see and we do not understand too. Perhaps we were affected by our humanity then we could not able be as the world wants us to be, to see in every peccadillo a sign to the special kingdom.

Oh! How stupid we are when we claim acumen and knowledge! We do not know anything about ourselves, we do not know about life except what we want to delude ourselves that we know. We quarrel with the truth as if it is our eternal enemy and devil holds all the contradictions. How naïve we are when we always ask about life and its secret as if we just created to solve the puzzles! Only now I know that life is easy and complex just like pants' zipper.

According to the experts: "As much as Man grows up as much as he revealed the truth of things obviously, and as much as he learns something new as much as he gets closer from the fact. Every day Man matures and his ideas and vision of the world mature too. That is the philosophy of the Supreme entities, and the secret of our research and endless questions." I say: "As much as Man grows up as much as he further away from the truth, and as much as he learns something new as much as he gets less knowledge. And as much as he matures as much as he becomes more stupid and naive!"
}

\end{document}\includegraphics[]{test-style32.pdf}
```

THIS IS is style 06 modified template

```
\cxset{style06/.style={
 name={Chapter},
 numbering=arabic,
 number font-size=\Huge,
 number font-family=\calligra,
 number font-weight=\calligra,
 number color= black!90,
 number before=\hspace*{-30pt},
 number dot=,
 number after=,
 number position=rightname,
 chapter font-family=\rmfamily,
 chapter font-weight=\calligra,
 chapter font-size=\LARGE\calligra,
 chapter before={\vspace*{20pt}\par\hfill},
 chapter after={\hfill\hfill\par},
 chapter color={black!90},
 title beforeskip={\vspace*{50pt}},
 title afterskip={\vspace{3.5pt}\par},
 title before={\hfill},
 title after={\hfill\hfill},
 title font-family=\rmfamily,
 title font-color= black!90,
 title font-weight=\normalfont,
 title font-size=\LARGE,
 title spaceout=soul,
 }}

\cxset{style06}

\chapter{Crimson Moon}
\renewcommand{\DefaultLhang}{0.1}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\calligra}
\setlength{\DefaultFindent}{9.5pt}
\setlength{\DefaultNindent}{0pt}

\lettrine{\textcolor{orange}{O}}{}nce upon an incendiary sand, this wind was playing with a climate known by nomads as harsh, inhabited by dusty fever and familiar to the cold-blooded snakes and invertebrates. This wind was two-sands away or whistling from an immemorial mirage which landed on the wing of a mythical bird that beaten the legends then flew in a red sky forever. Its blood -which was the only sign of optimism, was sunken in an inch of water, its saliva -which had spilt for the first time when it saw me- It saw me again and did not spill. There is no way to bet, the wound is sinking in the cactus thorn, and in the scales of lizards that adept at deception. The mirage is a birthmark of the Western desert, and its only point of weakness.\medskip
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{/Users/chemotkbilo/Desktop/DesktopWallpapers/backgrounds_home.jpg}

\caption{I am}
\end{figure}

A mirage

\begin{lstlisting}
 The beautiful Mirage re-emerge (here i want to have a box like conversation between two people) ,
\end{lstlisting}

Over the full song, the singer kept following the musical scale, but he suddenly fell at the edge of the river when frogs' disturbing sounds escalated. Let us return to the desert where the wind is a single queen of people who love the heat, even those nomads who were afraid of the wind's wrath when it spit sand on their faces and when horses find their way to flee. Oh fair Queen! Some of your people still suffering from headaches and dryness, and there is no refuge from you except these cracks. I love you because you're the only one who can cheat me and I do not dare to speak! I love you because I love to sleep! I love you because you are who I scared and I love her approaching! I love you because we are ancient in the slavery convoy heading north where this wound is an abandoned direction and deniable niche. Nomads worship the wind in secret, and bury oblations under the sands of this desert.
```

Results

[image: chapter 1]
[image: chapter 2]

Comment: Does removing or commenting out the line `\usepackage{../phd}` make the problem go away? If the problem remains when the line is removed, remove it from your example since we don't know what's in it. If the problem goes away when you remove that line, then the contents of `phd.sty` become critical to solving the problem, and you should go through it commenting out lines until you find the minimum code from it that shows your problem.

Comment: Please note the package is not ready for production yet. It  still has many bugs.

Comment: @Mike Renfro the problem still persist.after either removing the line or commenting out

Comment: @Yiannis Lazarides i am aware that the package is still buggy! but i was wondering, what if i was to accomplish the same design without using the package, how should i proceed? thank you for you prompt response! finding a a sample or template for a novel in Tex is pretty much almost impossible haha, until i ran to your package !

Comment: The code as posted simply cannot be built, with or without the `phd.sty` from Yiannis. You have a `\begin{figure}` with no closing `\end{figure}`, and if you commented out the line with `phd.sty`, you'd have nothing defining `\cxset`. Adding `\input{style06}` with the file you include puts a `\chapter` before the `\begin{document}` (and also a figure and a code listing), as well. It will be very difficult to get help with what you've provided.

Comment: See also [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) and [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225).

Comment: thanks you, i will work on it, and repost my work - in hope it works- *fingers crossed*

Comment: Modified the code and it works now - i would like to hear your inputs on how to make it better, for example making the starting letter of the chapter bigger etc. i also posted the results above

Comment: the drastic slant of the font used for "Chapter N" makes the line appear to be shifted to the right rather than centered.  this is probably most easily adjusted by a fixed manual "backspace" -- `\hspace*{-<suitable dimension>}` before "Chapter".

Comment: Please define 'better'. One person's 'better' is another person's 'mess'. What changes do you want to make? What don't you like? You've said you want the lettrine to be bigger, but we don't know what the 'etc.' means. In any case, please add all of this information to your question so that it is not buried in comments.

Comment: Also, please read the links people provided concerning code pruning and MWEs. This will not compile as it is since it requires code not present in a standard installation and a file located under your home directory on your computer.

Answer (score 3):

a working answer, 
but before posting the working example in order for this to work, you must install Yiannis Lazarides package from his [github](https://github.com/yannisl/phd) it is necessary for the code to compile. instruction on how to install phd package available on his Github (a beautiful package - buggy but still awesome) TO INSTALL: UNZIP THE FILES, and on terminal (linux and OS X) or cmd (windows)

```
 pdflatex phd.dtx
 makeindex -s gind.ist -g phd
```

i used style06 template available on the package. my modified template is also above. i was not sure how to produce MWE since it needs phd package installed also \usepackage{phd} , hence not everyone have phd package from Yiannis [Github style06 unchanged minimal](https://github.com/yannisl/phd/blob/master/styles/style06.tex). Therefore you WILL need phd package from [github](https://github.com/yannisl/phd) if you are interested. the mwe code i made is below, and phd package is on github, but the code works if you installed the package.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{phd}
\sethyperref
\input{defaultstyle}
\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\input{./styles/style06} 
\chapter{title}
\cxset{style06}
\expandafter\epigraph{text.}{name}
\lettrine{\textcolor{orange}
\lipsum
\section{Test}
\lipsum
\subsection{Test}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Test}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

it feels superb to learn and figure everything out on your own with small helps here and there. i learned a lot, and i am happy to be the one who answer my own question. if anyone has a question about my answer please do not hesitate to ask or PM me and i will make a video if that help

Comment: How to install phd in windows vista I tried without success!

Comment: step to step please Iried pdflatex phd.dtx but there are few errors am I the only one ?

Comment: On windows, I believe it is "phd-lua phd.dtx" . I am using it with OSX and sometimes arch Linux. His github repository details the installation procedure. There will be some errors due to the package not "stable". However, even with errors , try to run some of the examples from the package inside "test" folder

Comment: Thank you I have follow instructions given in github but I  get phd.pdf empty and problems of fonts  (not found !) I'm really desappointed.

Comment: For example font Hack can not be found